# How to read 2d array file from bottom-left to top line by line using Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working on a pyqt5 program that saves a 2d float array data with `np.savetext`. The saved file, which is convenient for me, looks like this:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

Can anyone help me to read this file from bottom-left to top line by line for obtaining this:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |

Comment: By "read" do you mean the raw loading of the text file into string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd better have all lines read first. I'm doing this array in one string, you can easily adopt it for file. And then transform it to your liking, for example, flip.

```
import numpy as np
import io

backwards_array = "\
|13  |14  |15  |16  |17  |18|\n\
|7  |8  |9  |10 |11 |12|\n\
|1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |6|\n"

buf = io.StringIO(backwards_array)
arr_of_arrs = np.empty((0,0), int)
lines = buf.readlines()
for line in lines:
  arr = np.fromstring(line[1:-2], dtype=int, sep='|')
  arr_of_arrs = np.vstack([arr_of_arrs, arr]) if arr_of_arrs.size else arr

print(np.flip(arr_of_arrs, axis=0))
```

> [[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
> [ 7  8  9 10 11 12]
> [13 14 15 16 17 18]]

You  might also want to have it 1d straight away:

`print(np.flip(arr_of_arrs, axis=0).flatten())`

> [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18]

Comment: 1000 of thanks Artym. That's exactly what I want. :-)

Answer (score 0):

this should do

```
with open('lesavedfile.np') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    
new_lines = lines[:2]+list(reversed(lines[2:]))
```

Comment: Thank you for this replay. After correcting the mistike (lines2:] ---> lines[:2] ) the program don't give me what I expect !

Comment: @LaidMessaoudi you corrected it in the wrong way: `lines[:2]+list(reversed(lines[2:]))`. I suggest you to read more about python slice notation. Also, if you get an invalid or unexpected result, you should also tell *what* you get.

Comment: After printing the new_lines variable, this is the result: newlines= ['13\t14\t15\t16\t17\t18', '7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t12', '', '1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6']. It's the same as the original file.